# How to use a table name as a variable with entity?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

In VB .net I am using Entity framework, I have a form (frmAdd) containing a DataGridView its data source is:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.Genders.ToList
```

I want to make (Genders) a variable to be like that:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.tblName.ToList
```

And here is my code:

```
Public Class frmAdd

Dim myEntity As New HRDataEntities

Dim tblName As String

Private Sub frmAdd_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.Genders.ToList

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       tblName = "Jobs"
```

The next line is not accepted in editor:

```
       DataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.tblName.ToList

       DataGridView1.Refresh()

    End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: What is the error message? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @Renan ,, No error message. But the vb editor doesn't accept that and saying "tblName is not a member of 'HRDataEntities'."

Comment: Did you try remove the `.ToList` using only `DataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.tblName`

Comment: @Renan .. Yes I did, but no way..

Comment: Could you add your HRDataEntities class in the question? I think that it will work if your HRDataEntities inherits from a Entity Framework class called DbContext and if the tblName is a HRDataEntities property declared as a DbSet property

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DbContext.Set Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to get a `DbSet` dynamically. But instead of passing it a name, you have to call it with a `Type`.

```
Dim entityType As Type

entityType = GetType(Jobs)
DataGridView1.DataSource = context.[Set](entityType).Cast(Of Object)().ToList()
```

Comment: The editor not accepting (.ToList) , so I removed it but an error raised (System.NotSupportedException: 'Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.')

Comment: You might be missing `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the code.

Comment: No, I don't miss that. but I want to clear that the (ToList) is not an option appear in the drop down list while I am editing the code. but I can select for example (ToString) and this show a blank datagridview.

Comment: Okay, I get it. The problem is that in this dynamic case the DbSet returned is not typed, I.e. it implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable(Of T)`. Therefore, as you don't know the real type at compile time, you must cast it to `Object`.

Comment: Would you explain more for me?

Comment: The extension methods like `ToList`, `Select`, `Where` work only on types known at compile time. So `context.Set(Of Genders)().ToList()` works, but `context.Set(someType).ToList()` does not, since `someType` could be any type. But you can cast it to `Object`, since every type is an `Object`. And then `ToList` returns a `List(Of Object)`. You cannot be dynamic and strongly typed at the same time.